# Comparison between Beatrice of Much Ado About Nothing and Offred of The Handmaids tale

Tags: character-analysis, william-shakespeare, much-ado-about-nothing, the-handmaids-tale, margaret-atwood

> Compare and contrast the way Offred in Margaret Atwood’s *The Handmaid’s Tale* and Beatrice in William Shakespeare’s *Much Ado about Nothing* view romantic love. Discuss 2 similarities and 2 differences (4 points). Explain how Offred’s and Beatrice’s views of love change over the course of the novel and the play (2 points).

Here is my attempt:

- Similarities

  1. Both crave for a romantic relationship.
- Differences:

  1. Beatrice shows that she doesn’t like men at first and claims that she never wants to get married. Offred has nothing against marriage and in fact marries the man she has an affair with (her husband).
  2. Beatrice doesn’t believe in love and marriage but in the end falls in love with Benedick and marries him.

I don’t know the exact difference in views of love for Offred though. Please help me with another similarity and difference too. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Exchange. SE is not like other sites. We are a question-and-answer board, not a discussion site. While Literature SE may allow questions which are used for schoolwork if they are also helpful to the broader community, this is not. It's a literary analysis question. If you haven't read and/or discussed the pieces in question, then having us give you the answers isn't helpful to you or to future visitors to the site.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - literary analysis is on topic :). We've got a meta discussion about this somewhere. However, this question could benefit from being narrowed down to ask about just one thing. While it's okay but not great in its current form, with a little editing this could become a good question.